# Nullable parameters during an update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Im trying to update a table based on several update increments.

My document review table currently looks like this:

```
| ID | Review Date         | Provisional Review Date | Final Review Date   | Provisional Review Timeframe (hours) | Final Review Timeframe (hours) |
|----|---------------------|-------------------------|---------------------|--------------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| 1  | 2018-03-12 00:00:00 | 2018-03-10 00:00:00     | 2018-03-11 00:00:00 | 24                                   | 48                             |
```

The Stored Procedure (**insertDocumentReview**) looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertDocumentReview]
    --parameters
    @id int,
    @ReviewDate datetime2 = null,
    @ProvisionalReviewDate datetime2 = null,
    @FinalReviewDate datetime2 = null,
AS
BEGIN

        UPDATE  [DocumentReview] 
        SET     ReviewDate = @ReviewDate,
                ProvisionalReviewDate = @ProvisionalReviewDate,
                FinalReviewDate = @FinalReviewDate,
                --the following columns are calculated based on the values of the columns populated above
                [ProvisionalReviewTimeframe] = (DATEDIFF(SECOND, [ProvisionalReviewDate], [ReviewDate]) / 3600.0),
                [lReviewTimeframe] = (DATEDIFF(SECOND, [FinalReviewDate], [ReviewDate]) / 3600.0),
        WHERE   [Id] = @id

END
```

---

### The problem

I then execute the stored procedure 4 times with varying parameters set to `null` like this:

```
-- 1) Insert Final Review Date
EXEC insertDocumentReview 1, NULL, NULL, '2018-03-14 10:19:10'

-- 2) Insert Provisional Review Date
EXEC insertDocumentReview 1, NULL, '2018-03-13 12:19:10', NULL

-- 3) Insert Review Date
EXEC insertDocumentReview 1, '2018-03-15 10:19', NULL, NULL

-- 4) Insert all dates
EXEC insertDocumentReview 1, '2018-03-15 10:19', '2018-03-13 12:19:10', '2018-03-14 10:19:10'
```

- At executions 1 and 2 Provisional Review Timeframe and Final Review Timeframe should be null as they are set by the calculation
- At execution 3 the reviewDate is introduced so Im expecting the Provisional Review Timeframe and Final Review Timeframe columns to be populated based off the calculation **but they are not**.
- At execution 4 the calculations for Provisional Review Timeframe and Final Review Timeframe are calculated and I will see 24 and 48 respectively.

I need to know why the calculation does not calculate at execution 3.

Comment: Can you post the entire procedure signature? You have 3 parameters defined but in the code where you call it there are 4.

Comment: @SeanLange Good spot, I missed the id parameter, will update now

Comment: How about the table definition and a sample row where your third execution doesn't work. You also need to explain what is not working as expected. Create enough detail so we have something to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all or nothing behavior. You cannot refer to value from same execution and get new value.

Example:

```
create table t(x INT, y INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 10);
update t
SET x = y,
    y = x;
select * from T;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fc1a4ecf792d668bb34e5d3994aa6abb)**

```
-- Before
x = 5, y = 10
-- After
x = 10, y = 5
-- in step 3 you want this to work like this
x= 10, y = 10
```

Values are swapped, but in step 3 you want to get new value from prev column, which won't happen.

I suggest to try:

```
UPDATE  [DocumentReview] 
SET     ReviewDate = @ReviewDate,
        ProvisionalReviewDate = @ProvisionalReviewDate,
        FinalReviewDate = @FinalReviewDate,

      [ProvisionalReviewTimeframe] 
        = (DATEDIFF(SECOND, [ProvisionalReviewDate], @ReviewDate) / 3600.0),
      [lReviewTimeframe] 
        = (DATEDIFF(SECOND, [FinalReviewDate], @ReviewDate) / 3600.0),
WHERE   [Id] = @id
```

Comment: Well spotted. I was still trying to wrap my head around the code. I should pulled it down and formatted it so I could it. :)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer makes a lot of sense and has solved the problem. Many thanks